# Searching on 2D array

Tags: c

I have a 2D array of integers NxM, which is already sorted. User will provide an integer and I have to search if it's on the array or not.
I want searching being done in a certain way. First I will check the last element of the first row. If the given number is greater I will move to the last element of the next row. If it's smaller I will do a linear search on that row.

My problem is that I can't find a way to point search starting from the last element of each row. In the way I have it now is just a normal linear search.

```
int i, j;
for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    for (j=0; j<M; j++){
      if(array[i][j] == key){
        row = i+1;
        col = j+1;
        return 1;                  
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The last element of a row is `array[i][M-1]`

Comment: So use `if (key <= array[i][M-1])`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you can access the last column of the matrix by fixing column value to `M-1` & varying `row-indexes` :

```c
// rows : N
// cols : M
// matrix : array
int found = 0;
// narrowing to a row
for (int ri = 0; ri < rows; ++ri) {
    if (key <= matrix[ri][cols - 1]) {
        // Linear Search Row
        for (int ci = 0; ci < cols; ++ci) {
            if (key == matrix[ri][ci]) {
                found = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks SparKot. That worked as I was looking for!

Comment: I would just put the second loop inside the `if` of the first one.